# Segmentation Fault when comparing strings from vectors in C++

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, string-comparison

I have my code as shown below. The words are read in from two files and need to be checked to see if there is an occurrence of a word in both files. I keep getting a seg fault after it matches the first word in both and adds it to the new vector. I added print statements earlier and it keeps running through the loop with the int n parameter before it hits the seg fault. I am rather new to C++ so the most basic way to help would be preferred.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <locale>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    vector<string> wordOne;
    vector<string> wordTwo;

    fileOne.open(argv[2]);
    fileTwo.open(argv[3]);
    while (fileOne >> wordsFirstFile) {
        wordOne.push_back(wordsFirstFile);
     }
    while (fileTwo >> wordsSecondFile) {
        wordTwo.push_back(wordsSecondFile);
     }
    fileOne.close();
    fileTwo.close();
    int sizeOneWord = wordOne.size();
    int sizeTwoWord = wordTwo.size();
    vector<string> printWords;
    int m = 0;
    int n = 0;
    for (m = 0; m <= sizeOneWord; m++) {
        for (n = 0; n <= sizeTwoWord; n++) {
             if (wordOne[m] == wordTwo[n]) {
                 printWords.push_back(wordOne[m]);
             }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `sizeOneWord` is one. That means there's only one legal index into `wordOne`. But your loop will loop twice, once with `m == 0` and once with `m == 1`. So if there's one element in the vector, you will try to access two elements. You need to change both `<=` comparisons to `<`.

Comment: Or use a foreach loop: `for(const auto& lhs : sizeOneWord)`

Comment: @JamesPicone just for completeness, you probably mean `for (const auto& s: wordOne);`

Comment: I tried changing the comparisons at the top and that didn't change anything. The sizes were correct when I checked them before. I used essentially the same code for integers and it worked fine, so I'm confused as to why strings can't work the same way.

Comment: @Tas oops! Yes I do.

Comment: @user2217 Reading 'past the end' of a vector (which this code is doing) is 'undefined behaviour', and undefined behaviour is allowed to do whatever it wants, which includes 'appearing to work'. Practically speaking, a string is a complex object and an int isn't, so likely the memory that's being interpreted as a string doesn't meet some internal requirements for how a string functions and causes a segmentation fault.

Comment: @JamesPicone okay that makes more sense. Thanks

Comment: With the comparisons fixed, does the code still fault? If so, can you show us the changes you made and what input data you tested with so we can replicate the problem?